# What are the software tools used for customizing secret sharing and network steganography, which can be used for enhancing secret data transmission?

Tags: secret-sharing, steganography

My goal is to enhance by bringing some changes to these techniques and schemes so that any improvements can be brought to them. So I tried to find some of the tools and came up with these:

**Secret Sharing Protocol:**

Cryptool: Cryptool is an open-source software suite that includes various cryptographic tools and modules. It provides a platform for designing, simulating, and analyzing secret sharing protocols.

Sharemind: Sharemind, as mentioned earlier, is a framework for secure multi-party computation. It includes secret sharing as one of its core functionalities and offers a programming environment for customization and evaluation of secret sharing protocols.

ThresholdCrypto: ThresholdCrypto is a Python library that provides implementations of various threshold cryptography protocols, including secret sharing schemes. It allows you to customize and evaluate different protocols in a programming environment.

**Network Steganography:**

StegExpose: StegExpose, as mentioned before, is a tool for detecting steganographic content in files and network traffic. While its primary purpose is detection, it can be used to evaluate and analyze different network steganography techniques.

OpenStego: OpenStego, also mentioned earlier, is an open-source steganography software that supports various steganographic methods for hiding data within files. It offers customization options and can be used for evaluating different steganography techniques.

StegDetect: StegDetect is a software tool designed to detect steganography in image files. While its focus is on detection, it can be useful for evaluating the effectiveness of different steganographic algorithms.